# Dynamically creating drawables

Tags: java, android, drawable, android-drawable

I am trying the create a button that has a ring around it (it is for a clicker-counter app). Currently I am creating this ring a drawable then setting the background of the button to the drawable. The code in the drawable is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="@dimen/large_inner_radius"
    android:thickness="@dimen/large_thickness"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="@color/large_circle" />

</shape>
```

The Dimentions are in another dimens file, here they are

```
<dimen name="large_inner_radius">200dp</dimen>
<dimen name="large_thickness">10dp</dimen>
```

The problem is, I need the be able to scale these drawables for different size android screens and I would like to be able to do this dynamically from code. I can not just scale the drawable because the thickness of the ring would be wrong.

[image: Desired Screen Design]

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please post large_inner_radius

Comment: No you are going about this the wrong way. Android already takes care of scaling etc. You can define separate drawables for different screen sizes or densities. You should **NEVER** try to manually scale it in code. Take a look at [**this**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: I have looked into using all the different DPI and screen size folders, the issue is that it get very confusing very quickly because I have circles that overlay the out square of another circle and so forth

Comment: create dimension file for each screen sizes like ldpi mdpi hdpi and so on and keep it into their respective values folder and as per your requirement set the size to

<dimen name="large_inner_radius">200dp</dimen>
<dimen name="large_thickness">10dp</dimen> this values

Comment: Then I still have to use code to get everything position properly? Would it be under for example values-hdpi/dimens.xml? Also does values-hdpi superseed the values in the just values folder?